# adding office365 group to Sharepoint site collection administrators thorugh Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, azure-automation

I am trying to add one of office 365 group as a site collection administrator in SharePoint online site through PowerShell or API but I am not getting any solution for this.
i can do it manually from site UI but I want to automate it so looking for Powershell or API.
[image: can add through UI]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PnP PowerShell cmdlet `Add-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin -owners`.

Reference:https://github.com/pnp/powershell/blob/dev/documentation/Add-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin.md

The things we need to notice is that unlike the documentation said, we need to use the `LoginName` like `i:0#.f|membership|user1@contoso.sharepoint.com`

So for an O365 group, it shall be like `c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider|<Object ID>`

For Security group it shall be like `c:0t.c|tenant|<Object Id>`

You can get the Object ID for group in Azure AD.
[image]

Comment: I am getting this error   "Exception occurred while trying to add the user: "The specified user c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider|*************-461f-bcaf-51235ee3369b could not be found.". User will be skipped."
through i have put the correct group ID.

Comment: I am adding a security group

Comment: it worked for me i used c:0t.c|tenant|<UNKNOWN-GUID>

Comment: @amyy Glad to hear you get it done. Yes O365 group and security group are different and you will need to have different prefix. I will update your answer in my reply and please accept it as answer